# Using a custom property in if statements in the BGE

Tags: python, game-engine

Here is my code, I think I have a way to have it do what I want, just not sure how to access a custom property on an object. I thought the code I had was right, but I feel like I'm missing something (or did something wrong).

The goal is so that whenever I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> it increases the value of the custom property 'unit'  by 1, thus changing which trackObject I am placing when I click. (the TAB/Property change is done in the logic bricks).  At this point I know I'm trying to use the property in the code, just pretty sure I'm typing it out wrong.

```
import bge
import bpy
from bge import render
render.showMouse(1)

def main():

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

trackObject1 = scene.objects ["trackObject1"]
trackObject2 = scene.objects ["trackObject2"]
trackObject3 = scene.objects ["trackObject3"]
trackObject4 = scene.objects ["trackObject4"]
trackObject5 = scene.objects ["trackObject5"]

unit = bpy.data.objects["player"]["unit"] #pretty sure this isnt right...   

mouseOver = cont.sensors ["mouseOver"]
click = cont.sensors ["click"]
readyMove = cont.sensors ["readyMove"]

trackTo = cont.actuators ["trackTo"]
move = cont.actuators ["move"]

if mouseOver.positive:
    target = mouseOver.hitObject
    if click.positive and unit == 1:
        trackObject1.worldPosition = mouseOver.hitPosition 
        else if click.positive and unit == 2:
        trackObject2.worldPosition = mouseOver.hitPosition
        else if click.positive and unit == 3:
        trackObject3.worldPosition = mouseOver.hitPosition
        else if click.positive and unit == 4:
        trackObject4.worldPosition = mouseOver.hitPosition
        else if click.positive and unit == 5:
        trackObject5.worldPosition = mouseOver.hitPosition


if readyMove.positive:
    cont.activate(move)
    cont.activate(trackTo)

if own.getDistanceTo(trackObject1) < 2:
    else if own.getDistanceTo(trackObject2) < 2:
    else if own.getDistanceTo(trackObject3) < 2:
    else if own.getDistanceTo(trackObject4) < 2:
    else if own.getDistanceTo(trackObject5) < 2:
    cont.deactivate(move)
    cont.deactivate(trackTo)

main()
```

Comment: This answers my question from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69422. You want a switching/toggling operation.

Answer (score 2):

You debugged part of your problem in your code. You mixed blender's api (bpy), in with the game engine's (bge).

The line `unit = bpy.data.objects["player"]["unit"]` will do nothing in the game.
You already defined the `scene` in your script, so that line with `bpy` needs to be:

```
unit = scene.objects["player"]["unit"]
```

That line is accessing the game property "unit" on the object named "player".

---

Your last if statement is not correct. You need something in the if statement's bodies, even just `pass` will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help,  i got it to work!     I'm sure ill be asking more questions later, but for now I can continue!

Comment: @TimFromInternet since this solved your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/278094) the answer. That makes this as solved, and lets other know that there is an answer that worked for you.